# How to set a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have this code:

```
if  [ -f "/mnt/usb/test/linuxConfig.json" ]
   then
   echo "usb på plats"
```

What I want is when the file is found ( aka the usb is mounted) to set a variable as true.

I want to write a script that checks if the the usb is mounted and in case is
not to try to mount it and if it fails to reboot the pi.

I need the variable to be true or false since I want to use a `sleep` command as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really see where you want to use that variable as you could easily do everything you might want to do in the correct `if`-`then`-`else` branch:

```
if [ -f "my/file" ]; then
    echo 'Filen finns tillgänglig / the file is available'
else
    echo 'Filen är inte där / the file is not there'
    mount /mnt/something || { sleep 120; reboot; }
    # or  ... || shutdown -r +2 'Rebooting due to failed mount'
fi
```

To use a "boolean" variable:

```
found=0
[ -f "my/file" ] || found=1

if (( !found )); then
    # file was not found
else
    # file was found
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use any nonempty value as "true":

```
if [ -f /mnt/ust/test/linuxConfig.json ] ; then
    var=1
fi

if [ "$var" ] ; then
    echo Var is true
else
    echo Var is false
fi
```